# Can I develop a new Laravel project displaying a 'Missing npm modules' warning in Netbeans?

Tags: node.js, netbeans, laravel-5

I am trying to learn Laravel.

I installed it and created a project.

Using Netbeans I see an error mark on the project name that says:

> Missing npm modules.

I installed node.js, clicked resolve, pointed the paths to node.exe and npm.cmd

I still see the error, NetBeans says:

> npm(myproject) Running.

The error is still there but now when I click `Resolve`, the sentence 
“Missing npm modules” is greyed out, and the `Resolve` button does nothing.

Is there anything else I should do?

Do I need to do all of this to develop with Laravel?

Can I just continue developing with this error?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what's going on in Laravel these days, especially why you would need npm since it's a PHP framework built with composer... but you might just need to do `npm install` in your project to download your dependencies. Do this from the directory where the package.json file is found. This is what you would do for a node.js app...

Answer (score 4):

[No you don't.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation) Node packages are required for asset management, which you can actually do without, or simply install your own set of tools. For your case, simply run

```
npm install
```

Make sure you have node installed